# delete select option inside div with siblings()

Tags: php, jquery

I wrote this PHP code:

```
for ($i=1; $i < 11; $i++)
{
    $output.='
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Schedule priority: '.$i.' </label><br>
      <select class="form-control selectDisable">
        <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
        <option value="1">Schedule: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Restday: Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Schedule: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Restday: Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Schedule: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Restday: Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Schedule: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Restday: Thrusday</option>
        <option value="5">Schedule: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Restday: Friday</option>
        <option value="6">Schedule: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Restday: Saturday</option>
        <option value="7">Schedule: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Restday: Sunday</option>
      </select>
    </div>';
}
```

With Jquery I'm looking for delete selected option on siblings selects with this code:

```
   $(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $(this).siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
  });
```

It doesn´t work, maybe because the selects are inside `<div class="form-group">`if i delete that tag the code works fine.

How I can run my code without remove the div tags?

Comment: `$(this).siblings()` need to be `$('.selectDisable').children()`

Comment: Seeing as there are ten selects with the same options, I'm guessing the point is to remove a selected option from all the other selects, but not the current one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Siblings` are elements of the same level. Your `select`s are in different levels. I suppose you can just select all `select`s without `siblings`:

```
$(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $('.selectDisable').find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```

If you don't want to remove value from **current** `select` - use `not`:

```
$(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $('.selectDisable').not(this).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```